# Not able to use NativeProcessInfo and other related classes

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

I have an AIR application in which I have to start some native applications in a windows machine.But the problem I am facing is that whenever I try to create a `NativeProcess` instance,I am getting a compiler error because `NativeProcess` is not getting imported into the project.I tried `import flash.desktop.*;` Even then no use.I have also added `<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>`
in the application descriptor file.I am using FlashBuilder 4 with Flex 4 SDK

Anything else I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Show your code?  It sounds like the AIR libraries may be missing from your project, which means there is either something wrong w/ your project setup or your SDK.

Comment: Ya.I had to set up AIR 2 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.Actually,I was under the wrong impression that FlashBuilder 4 ships with AIR 2 SDK(needed for NativeProcess and related classes).So I did a fresh install of AIR 2 SDK by following the steps in this [link](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/air/2/releasenotes_developers.html#h) and the issue was solved.

Comment: Great; be sure to mark your answer as the correct one so that others who come across this question will know the solution.